# Python for loop stops working after first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop that returns zeros after the first iteration. I have it print out i, so I know it is actually looping through, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be calling my function, new_lattice, after the first iteration.

```
N=[4,8,16,20,25]
for i,j in enumerate(N):
    print(i)
    init_lattice=np.ones((j,j))
    #new_lattice is a function that returns multiple lists 
    data=new_lattice(init_lattice,j)
    print (data[1])
```

The print should print out one of the lists returned by the function, but except for the first iteration all the elements of the list are zero. If I call the function outside the loop with N=any value, then the elements are non zero, so it seems to be the loop that's the problem. I have another python file that has exactly the same loop, but that one works, so I don't understand why this doesn't!

Here is the full code including the function:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random as rn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temp1= np.arange(2.0, 3.0, 0.1)
temp=enumerate(temp1)
number_of_sweeps=200
eqm_sweeps=50

def new_lattice(lattice,L):
    delta_E=np.zeros((L,L))
    mag=np.zeros(number_of_sweeps)
    mag1=np.zeros(len(temp1))
    mag2=np.zeros(len(temp1))
    mag4=np.zeros(len(temp1))
    for n, T in temp:
        for sweep in range(number_of_sweeps+eqm_sweeps):
            for i in range(L):
                for j in range(L):
                    Si=lattice[i,j]
                    sum_Sj=lattice[i,(j+1)%L]+lattice[(i+1)%L,j]+lattice[i,(j-1)%L]+lattice[(i-1)%L,j]
                    delta_E[i,j]=2*Si*sum_Sj

                    if delta_E[i,j] > 0.0 and rn.random() <  np.exp(-1*delta_E[i,j]/(T)):
                        lattice[i,j] *= -1
                    elif delta_E[i,j] <= 0.0:
                        lattice[i,j] *= -1
            if sweep>=eqm_sweeps:
                mag[sweep-eqm_sweeps]=abs(np.sum(lattice))
                mag1[n]=np.sum(mag)/number_of_sweeps
                mag2[n]=np.sum(mag**2)/((L**2)*number_of_sweeps)
                mag4[n]=np.sum(mag**4)/((L**2)*number_of_sweeps)

    return mag1, mag2,mag4,lattice
```

The code uses the Metropolis algorithm to simulate the Ising model.
The output looks like:

```
    0
[ 3323.37   3225.43   2912.865  2740.01   2392.66   2266.455  1964.165
  1804.22   1595.68   1317.135]
1
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
2
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
3
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
4
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

but I would expect the last 4 lists to have non-zero elements.

Comment: We don't have your `new_lattice` function, so this is not a verifiable, complete example. Please provide *enough* code to reproduce your error.

Comment: and an expected output would also be nice

Comment: You could add a `print` call in `new_lattice` to see if it actually enters there.

Comment: The problem Must be with your ``init_lattice`` or ``new_lattice``

Comment: It says 'bootstraps' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, bootstraps comes from another thing I was trying to do. I've removed that part of the code

Comment: `temp=enumerate(temp1)` in the global scope... and then `for n, T in temp:` in the function...

Comment: @Rawing, that works! Why does it make a difference where it's defined? Could you expand into an answer?

Comment: Please check the Stack Overflow's help article [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The first three components of `data` are arrays which only contain `0.` (followed by a nested array which only contains lists with `1.`).You can see that by adding `print(data)`. That's why `data[1]` returns an array with only `0.` in it. Simply put: your return value probably does not have the intended structure.

Comment: @FK82 The point is that the first three components shouldn't only contain zero. The return value has the structure I would expect, but the data was not being generated.

Comment: Defining temp inside the function solves the problem, but I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: @Fp3 Because it's an iterator and it gets consumed the first time you iterate over it. So you have to re-create a new iterator every time.

Comment: @Fp3 So your return value is a quadruple consisting of three arrays and one nested (2D-)array? Seems kind of odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are storing enumerate outside the function and looping.

```
temp=enumerate(temp1)
for n, T in temp:
```

After your first function call with j=4, enumerate temp exhausts and "for n, T in temp" does not work any more.

Use enumerate inside new_lattice function so that a enumerate object is generated on each function call.

```
for n, T in enumerate(temp1):
```

Sample output:

```
0
(array([ 15.07,  14.17,  14.03,  14.19,  12.95,  11.76,  11.07,  10.71,
        11.14,  11.01]), array([ 14.43625,  13.16625,  12.90875,  13.02875,  11.32125,   9.9925 ,
         8.89625,   8.52875,   8.89   ,   8.88625]), array([ 3479.785,  3070.425,  2948.195,  2955.275,  2419.065,  2109.61 ,
        1747.325,  1640.615,  1700.32 ,  1730.785]), array([[ 1., -1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1., -1.,  1.]]))
1
(array([ 57.34,  54.44,  52.75,  42.99,  43.95,  35.48,  31.77,  31.81,
        25.06,  22.71]), array([ 52.979375 ,  48.47     ,  45.4803125,  33.8340625,  33.2053125,
        24.343125 ,  20.0590625,  20.0928125,  13.17125  ,  11.6246875]), array([ 190270.6775 ,  166042.28   ,  146420.65625,  100278.72625,
         87279.49125,   58296.1425 ,   41876.73125,   42170.46125,
         20914.28   ,   18993.91375]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.]]))
......
......
```